# How to dynamically change .price field when Currency loaded from Cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, curry-currency-converter

I implemented JS Cookies (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to Curry Currency Plugin in order to make currency selection persistent. Below the implementation based on other entries in this page (I don't remeber where, sorry): https://gist.github.com/hitautodestruct/7e48a5dcab1d8c88f287

This is my question better formulated:

Maybe a silly question but, How do I update the "price" field after I load the page with the currency_name value from the cookie as base currency? Because despite that the dropdown changes to the new selected currency, the prices on the page doesn't change after reload.

Comment: Your initially loading up curry with a null value for `savedCurrency ` see [this line](https://gist.github.com/hitautodestruct/7e48a5dcab1d8c88f287#file-curry-with-jscookie-html-L19).